Challanging access by extracting JWT authorization from Cookie
I am using a Google authentication to generate JWT tokens (access token and refresh token), and send it to the client as HttpOnly cookies.
On my API currently a JwtBearer is set up, which expecting a Bearer authorization header.
I would like it to also seek that bearer token as access token cookie, could it be combined? or just set up for seeking JWT Bearer token in access token cookie?

A Middleware.
I've used a Middleware to extract the access_token HttpSecure cookie and add it the Authorization header incase it is empty or missing
